# Why does $\vec v \times \vec B$ change to $\vec a \cdot \vec B$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vectors

I was doing a question where the solution said this:

$$\vec F = q (\vec v \times \vec B)$$

$$m \vec a= q (\vec v \times \vec B)$$

$$ \therefore  \vec a  \cdot \vec B = 0     $$

$$(x\hat i + 7 \hat j) \cdot (7 \hat i - 3 \hat j)=0 $$

$$7x-21=0$$

$$x=3$$

Please explain why does the $\vec v \times \vec B$ turn into $\vec a  \cdot \vec B$, should it be $\vec a \times \vec B$ cause like $\vec v$ & $\vec a$ are also perpendicular to $\vec B$

Comment: I don't see where your $x$ comes from though. Are you missing an $x$ in the original equation?

Comment: @RC_23 x is coefficient of the icap of the a vector

Comment: Ok.  I recommend you examine the math coding I did by editing the question, and add that x in yourself. It's not difficult

Comment: @RC_23 Done thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a property of vectors.

The cross product of two vectors $\vec v \times \vec B$ will always be perpendicular to both of the original vectors $\vec v$ and  $\vec B$.

Because of this $\vec a$ is perpendicular to $\vec B$.  This in turn implies that the dot product $\vec a \cdot \vec B$ is zero.